# Why does an array in Powershell get prefixed with empty values when returned from a function?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a simple repro where I define an array and return it in a function.  My script simply calls this function, casting the result to a variable, then prints each element in that variable.  What I don't understand is why I'm getting empty entities at the beginning of the array.  This only happens if the array is created in a Function and returned.

Code:

```
function Get-Things
{
       $stuff = new-object system.collections.arraylist
       $stuff.Add("Zeroth")
       $stuff.Add("First")
       $stuff.Add("Second")
       $stuff.Add("Third")
               

    return $stuff
}

$stuffs = Get-Things

foreach($thingy in $stuffs)
{
    Write-Host($thingy)
}
```

Expected result:

```
Zeroth
First
Second
Third
```

Actual result:

```
0
1
2
3
Zeroth
First
Second
Third
```

Comment: The `.Add()` method on ArrayList returns the index number of each element added. You can suppress that output by using `$null = $stuff.Add(..)` or `$stuff.Add(..) | Out-Null`